# Trouble with Magento Module name in Parallel plesk. Issue seems like with Case sensitivity

Tags: magento-1

I am having trouble with my Magento module name in `parallel Plesk`. My module's name is like `ComPany/MYMODULE` and it works fine in localhost.

But I uploaded it to a live server in Parallel Plesk, I m getting error such as `Source model "mymodule/entity_attribute_source_yesnodefault" not found for attribute "mymodule_update_images"`

It seems case-sensitivity plays the role here. So I changed the `MYMODULE` folder to `my module` and changed `ComPany/mymodule/etc/config.xml` appropriately. But no use! Still, the local works fine and the Live server gives the error!

How can I overcome this error? If you have any Idea, share...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case sensitivity may indeed be your issue here. If the server is case sensitive and your local machine is not, you can expect this behaviour.

You should start all folder and file names in your module with capital letters. The model in question should have the following path:

```
app/code/local/ComPany/Mymodule/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Yesnodefault.php
```

Your `config.xml` file and `app/etc/modules` file should define your module name as `ComPany_Mymodule`, and the model configuration should map the lowercase `mymodule` to the classes in `ComPany_Mymodule_Model`:

```
<models>
    <mymodule>
        <class>ComPany_Mymodule_Model</class>
    </mymodule>
</models>
```

Comment: I would also add the suggestion of setting up a case-sensitive file partition for developing locally.